# AWS Cognito pass additional parameters to OIDC IDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, idp

I'm using AWS Cognito for my SSO and added a federated IDP (pingfederate). Cognito does not have any option to add additional query parameters that I want for ping federate (acr_values and prompt). There's no documentation around this in AWS as well.

Is there a way that we can force Cognito to send additional query parameters to a federated IDP? I've read that Auth0 has dynamic parameters that can work around this

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in this as well - I have the issue that I need to pass the parameter `idp` to the /authorize of the OIDC target and there is a field called `Identifier (optional)` but whatever I do, it does not include it.

[image]

Comment: It was such a pain to deal with for me. Tried the identifiers option as well to no avail. Anyway the original intent was for federated logouts, ended up using a 'hacky' approach by iframing the federated logout endpoint of the external oidc

Comment: So how did u obtain the final redirect URL?